# How does one place two buttons in one table cell with fluent bootstrap?

Tags: fluentbootstrap

I'm experimenting with Fluent Bootstrap but am finding the API documentation sparse. In the last cell of each table row I want to place two buttons (i.e. edit, delete). The problem is that the @row.TableData component builder is being passed two MVC HtmlStrings and is expecting a string? maybe

```
@using (var table = @Html.Bootstrap().Table().SetId("tblRoles").SetStyle(TableStyle.Bordered | TableStyle.Striped).SetResponsive().Begin())
    {
        @table.TableHeaderRow(
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id), 
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoleTag),
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status),
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name),
            ""
        )

        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            using (var row = @table.TableDataRow().Begin())
            {
                @row.TableData(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id))
                @row.TableData(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleTag))
                @row.TableData(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status))
                @row.TableData(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name))
                @row.TableData(
                    @Html.ButtonWithIcon(null, "Edit", "RolesAdmin", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs", title = "Edit" }, "icomoon-pencil-5")
                    @Html.ButtonWithIcon(null, "Delete", "RolesAdmin", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs", title = "Delete" }, "icomoon-remove-2")
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like most everything can use the begin method to create a wrapper around inner elements such as:

```
@row.TableData().Begin()
{
  @Html.ButtonWithIcon(null, "Edit", "RolesAdmin", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs", title = "Edit" }, "icomoon-pencil-5")
  @Html.ButtonWithIcon(null, "Delete", "RolesAdmin", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs", title = "Delete" }, "icomoon-remove-2")
}
```

This works and produces the desired markup.